# Whats the most efficient way to continuously update and track the score of an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A class of objects, Item, has a score attached to it based on its attributes. I need to apply the calculate_ranking method to the Item class continuously (ideally when any of an object's attributes are changed) and efficiently to calculate this score:

```
Item.all.each do |i|
    Item.update_counters i.id, :score_count =>  i.calculate_ranking
end
```

I've tried using attr_accessor :score(after adding a score column to the Item table) and after_initialize :calculate_ranking however it didnt work. Would be it possible to apply a custom counter cache to achieve this even though 'Score' isnt a separate model of its own? That is, without including:  Class Score; counter_cache => true; end.

Comment: AR object? Try a hook, like after_save.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand you issue quite well. However take a look at callbacks here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

and observers here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers